# Создание самоподписанной цепочки сертификатов OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

Возникла необходимость в создании самоподписанной цепочки сертификатов, используя инструменты библиотеки OpenSSL. В документации к OpenSSL не нашел каким образом это сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это реализовать ?

Answer (score 0):

Я правильно понимаю, что вам нужно не просто самоподписной сертификат, а именно цепочка сертификатов?

Другими словами, вам нужен собственный удостоверяющий центр, или certification authority.

Я такое делал. В двух словах это не объяснить, нужно написать простыню текста. К счастью, всё уже сделано до нас. В интернетах довольно много тьюториалов на нужную вам тему. Погуглите "openssl ca" или "openssl certification authority"

Задав вопрос гуглу "openssl CA своими руками", первой ссылкой я получил https://sgolubev.ru/openssl-ca/

Выглядит правдоподобно.